# memoized a closure and render callback with useCallback

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

let's I have a graphql mutation component, that I reuse in many places

```
const MarkAsViewed =({ type = 1, children }) => {
  const markAsViewed = (commitMutation) => (type) => {
    return commitMutation({
      variables: { type }
    });
  };

  return (
    <MarkAsViewedMutation
      mutation={MARK_AS_VIEWED_MUTATION}
      variables={{
        type,
      }}
    >
      {
        (commitMutation, { error, loading }) => children({
          markAsViewed: markAsViewed(commitMutation)
        })
      }
    </MarkAsViewedMutation>
  );
};
```

however since `markAsViewed` is a closure function, it will always return different function with different ref which means different for react.

this makes the child component to have to do a `useCallback` like:

```
const alwaysSameRefFunc = useCallback(()=>{ markAsViewed(), []}
```

above works but creates 2 problems:

1. I get linter warning saying I should add `markAsViewed` as dependency blah blah. which I cannot, because it triggers infinite loop (since it's different ref every time)
2. everyone that uses `<MarkAsViewed />` component will need to manually memoirzation

Ideally this is what I want, but it's an invalid code, because "markAsViewed" is not a react component and cannot have useCallback

```
const markAsViewed = (commitMutation) => useCallback((type) => {
    return commitMutation({
      variables: { type }
    });
  }, []);
```

any idea how can I solve the issue?

note: we are not ready to update Apollo version to have hoook yet

Comment: Well, I think the best solution would in fact be to use the built-in Apollo React hooks, but if you're not able to do so you could roll your own. You could build a custom useMutation hook and utilize useCallback inside of it.  Earlier versions of React-Apollo also have a ```Mutation``` component which takes care of most of the concerns for you.

Comment: well `MarkAsViewedMutation` is actually a Apollo `Mutation` component, it has different name because it's just a typed version of it

Comment: You can try: `const alwaysSameRefFunc = useCallback(markAsViewed, []}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following work?

```
const markAsViewed = commitMutation => type => {
  return commitMutation({
    variables: { type },
  });
};
const MarkAsViewed = ({ type = 1, children }) => {
  const fn = useCallback(
    (commitMutation, { error, loading }) =>
      children({
        markAsViewed: markAsViewed(commitMutation),
      }),
    [children]
  );
  return (
    <MarkAsViewedMutation
      mutation={MARK_AS_VIEWED_MUTATION}
      variables={{
        type,
      }}
    >
      {fn}
    </MarkAsViewedMutation>
  );
};
```

I'm not sure if that will work because it still depends on children, if that causes unnesesary renders then maybe post how MarkAsViewed component is rendered.